# Stop Spotlight from indexing Time Machine during certain hours?

Tags: time-machine, spotlight, indexing

It seems from reading other posts that it's impossible to stop spotlight indexing Time Machine, even when you put Time Machine in the privacy tab, because it's necessary for Time Machine's functionality. But is there any way to disable Spotlight indexing Time Machine during certain hours?

Comment: Shut the Mac down?

Comment: Presumably, you're experiencing heavy or excessive Spotlight processes, and you want to correct that, rather than actually disabling Spotlight?

Comment: What is problem that you are trying to solve by wanting to stop TM indexing? You should also specify the version of macOS.

Comment: On which machine is this an issue?